# ODBC/JDBC connection getting aborted after running for 1 hour?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, odbc, teradata, amazon-workspaces

My ODBC/JDBC exciting connection getting aborted after running for 1 hour? 
I am using amazon workspace to connect AWS machine. Is there a setting that might have causing my session to abort?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message from the database when the connection is aborted? Is the session running a workload at the time of the abort or idle?

Comment: sql assistant is failing with "software caused connection abort.". It is general error it gives. There is no rule defined from database side as I am able to run query using BTEQ (tcp connection). So there must be some AWS rule for ODBC/JDBC that is causing this.

Comment: Have you tried enabling KeepAlive in your JDBC or ODBC DSN settings? Is BTEQ running from a EC2 instance within AWS or from your client system outside AWS?

Comment: No I haven't tried it as I don't access to do it on Amazon workspace provided by client. BTW my BTEQ is running from a EC2 instance within AWS.